# Apple Books app and multiple desktops: How to stop app window to show on all desktops?

Tags: mojave, desktop, books

I am running macOS Mojave `10.14.4` with Books.app version `1.18`.

I use multiple desktops. When I open the Books app on one desktop, and then switch to another desktop, the Books app window shows on that desktop as well.

Even worse, any open Books app window pop in front of all other windows on that desktop.

I've tried assigning the Books application to a specific desktop, to all desktops and to None, and did not see any change in behavior.

This only happens with the Books app on my system.

[image]

What may be potentially causing this? How can I keep Books app window restricted to a single desktop?

Comment: I don't use Books, but I just ran a test. At default, though it showed as 'None' it did follow me. Once I set it to 'This Desktop' then it stopped following, & after setting back to 'None' it then stayed where I put it.

Comment: This works when opening the "Library". As soon as you open a specific book and assigning it to a specific desktop, the books still follows you around...

Comment: I tested with a book open. I can't repro your issue, sorry.

Comment: Hmm... I thought I'd have another look. Every launch I have to repeat the 'this desktop', then 'none' again, or it follows me.

Comment: It's a bit ridiculous. There should be a means to disable this behaviour for the Books app.

Comment: I just reported it in bug reporter. though I didn't know about assign to desktop feature.

Comment: I am sure it's a bug, I often encounter this issue and is very annoying

Answer (score 6):

I had the exact same problem, solution:

1. Open a book within the app
2. Right click on the dock icon
3. Options>Assign>This Desktop

Solved on macOS Catalina 10.15.4

Comment: This isn't a permanent solution because (as noted in the comments on the main question) every time you launch the Books app you have to repeat the steps (setting it to None and back to This Desktop) to get it to stop following you.